Django 4.2.11 is not supported with SQL Server
I am using Django 4.2.11 and connected to django-pyodbc-azure Version: 2.1.0.0.
The code was running fine but now I start getting an error and can't run it.
Did anyone knows how to solve this problem?
Error:

/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from asgiref<4,>=3.6.0->django) (4.9.0) (env) zinabadnan@Zinabs-MacBook-Air system % python3 manage.py runserver      Watching for file changes with StatReloader Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner     self.run()   File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper     fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run     autoreload.raise_last_exception()   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception     raise _exception[1]   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 394, in execute     autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper     fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/init.py", line 24, in setup     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate     app_config.import_models()   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked   File "", line 850, in exec_module   File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in      from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 57, in      class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in new     new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 243, in contribute_to_class     self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in getattr     return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in getitem     conn = self.create_connection(alias)   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection     backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend     return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)   File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "/Users/zinabadnan/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 12, in      raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d.%d is not supported." % VERSION[:3]) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 4.2.11 is not supported.

I am afraid to downgrade Django and some functions not work in my program.

Do you need to upgrade your SQL server package also? Maybe check the release notes for any changes

Have you considered looking for a different module? django-pyodbc-azure hasn't been updated in nearly six years and tells you in at least three places on the README that it only supports Django 2.1.

As @AlwaysLearning stated, perhaps look a new package that gets updates to work with the latest Django framework. Here seems to be a solid one, with more-or-less the same description of DB connection capabilities: https://pypi.org/project/mssql-django/

I have switched to MSSQL-Django and it works now.
